Is the intersection of the following sets countably infinite?

Let us take the set of all negative integers {-1, -2, -3 ...}

Let us artificially denote the position of each negative integer using the natural numbers such that -1 maps to position 1, -2 maps to position 2, -3 maps to position 3, and so on. (Position 1 is deemed to be artificial "prior" to position 2 and position 2 artificially "posterior" to position 1; this relation holds for all positions)

Let us create an infinite number of sets by considering each position. A set will be produced by each position such that the set includes the element in the position itself and all positions posterior to it, but it includes no elements in positions prior to it.


To illustrate the first three sets:
Set 1 = {-1, -2, -3 ... }
Set 2 = {-2, -3, -4 ... }
Set 3 = {-3, -4, -5 ... }
As you can tell, I'm not very good with mathematical formalism, but I hope the sets in consideration are clear. The question is, if I am to take the intersection of all of the sets that are under consideration, what will the cardinality of the resulting set be? My intuition tells me that it will be a countably infinite set (though I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be the empty set) but I can't think of any definitive proof that shows this. Assuming it is not the empty set, is there any way to deduce what members will be a part of the resulting set?
Please explain in a manner that is intelligible to someone who has virtually no background in mathematics; please do not assume that I have a background in mathematics. -Thank you

Hi Max, welcome to MSE. If I understand you right, I think the intersection is in fact empty. In general, to prove that $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap \dotsb$ is empty is the same as proving that for any element $x$, there is some $n$ such that $x$ is not in $S_n$. Do you see why those are the same, and why that's true in this case?

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you for welcoming me! I think I understand why proving that "for any element x, there is some n  such that x is not in Sn" is the same as proving that the intersection is empty. Does this hold in this case because, for every single element, there is some set that dosen't contain that element? As in, there is a set that doesn't contain -1, there is a set that dosen't contain -2, and so on, such that if we take the set of all of the "odd elements out", we result in the set of all negative numbers (which would be the union of all the sets)?

You’re totally right, at least in the start of your explanation: If you consider an element, say -n, then it is not a member of the set $S_{n+1}$. For example, -5 is not a member of $S_6$. To be in the intersection of all sets, is to be in every set, and by our observation there is no such element. Thus, the intersection is empty. I’m not sure exactly what you mean when you say “take the set of all of the “odd elements out””. The union is, as you said, the set of all negative integers; which is $S_1$, as each set is contained in the one before it.
